# Yakkov living in Egypt 17 years - connection to 210 years of servitude

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, number, calendar, avot-patriarch-fathers, egypt

Parshas Vayechi starts off that Yaakov lived in Egypt for 17 years. I was thinking that 17 years x 12 months = 204 months. Usually in 17 years there are 6 leap years which would increase the total number of months that Yaakov lived in Egypt to 210 months. Are there any commentaries that discuss a connection between Yaakov's 210 months in Egypt and the 210 years that the Jews were enslaved in Egypt?

Comment: Not exactly your question, but related - The sefer Arvei Nachal on this parsha shows how the 17 years that Yaakov lived in Egypt were equivalent to 190 years of separating the sparks of holiness from Egypt, so that Yisrael were able to leave Egypt 190 years early.

Comment: @MosheP: Can you link this?

Comment: The relevant page in the sefer Arvei Nachal is [here.](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19050&st=&pgnum=147&hilite=)

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34082

Comment: Ma'aseh Avos Siman l'Banim? From what I could tell from analyzing year 2448, the years back then can't be calculated based on today's calendar, so it won't help you to take years 2238-2255 to the Tur's charts to see how many were leap years.