# Yosef's 10% in Israel

Tags: number, eretz-yisrael, yosef

*Yosef* lived in the Holy Land from age six (*B'reshis* [30:25](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8225#v=25), [31:41](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8226#v=41)) until age seventeen ([*Rashi* to 37:34](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8232#showrashi=true&v=34)). This was eleven years, or 10% of his 110-year lifespan ([50:26](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8245#v=26)). Does anyone comment on this percentage (perhaps — and this is just a guess — in relation to the ten-percent tithe *Yaakov* promised from "all that You will give me" in [28:22](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8223#v=22), before *Yosef* was born)? What does the commentary say?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33784

Comment: Does the edit mean that you are now accepting comments from those not of authority, or does it mean that it is not even necessary to state that comments should be from someone of authority?

Comment: @Alex, well, answers always should contain support. I edited out the request for authority because I didn't want to preclude other kinds of support. For example, if no authority comments on this precisely but one comments on something related and an answer extrapolates from it, that may be good.